# How can I display real time data from a website on my Wordpresss website?

Tags: wordpress, api, plugins, wordpress-plugin-creation

My client has an account on a website where live data on their production is available.

Now, I have designed a WordPress site using Elementor where I need to fetch the data from his account and display it on this webpage as a live dashboard for the visitors.

Steps:

1. Log in to the client's account
2. Fetch data from his account
3. Display it on the webpage

How do I achieve this? Thanks in advance, I am really lost and all the answers for just fetching data from other websites, but how can I do the same by first logging into an account.